Why does the eigenvector I calculated for  in the spin-1 case give an incorrect probability for measuring ℏ?
I've been working on a problem involving a spin-1 particle in state:
$ |\chi _{z}^{0}>=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
 1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$
Which corresponds to the $m_{z}=0$ state of the spin-1 particle. The spin operator in the y-direction is given by:
$S_y = i \frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$
I was tasked with finding the probability of measuring the eigenvalue ℏ when the spin component in the y-direction is measured.
I found the eigenvector for this eigenvalue to be:
$| \psi_+ \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} -i \\ \sqrt{2} \\ i \end{pmatrix}
$
From this I determined the probability to be
$P(\hbar) = | \langle \psi_+ | \chi_0^z \rangle |^2$
$\langle \psi_+ | \chi_0^z \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} i & \sqrt{2} & -i \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \times \sqrt{2} = 1
$
This led to a probability of 100%, which does not overlap with the answers that state it should be 50%.
I eventually found out that the eigenvector should be:
$| \psi_+ \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ i\sqrt{2} \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}
$
My question is why is the eigenvector I initially determined incorrect? It is a normalized vector, so I struggle to find out why one shows a probability of 50% while the other has one of 100%.

You normalized incorrectly. Let's take the Eigenvector
$$|\psi\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}-i \\ \sqrt{2} \\ i\end{pmatrix}$$
Taking the inner product
$$\langle\psi|\psi\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}-i & \sqrt{2} & i\end{pmatrix}^* \begin{pmatrix}-i \\ \sqrt{2} \\ i\end{pmatrix}  = i(-i) + \sqrt{2}\sqrt{2} + (-i) i = 1 + 2 + 1 = 4$$
So you need to divide your vector by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}$ not $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. I suspect you forgot the complex conjugation.
